# Passing events through modules in Titanium SDK

Tags: javascript, module, titanium, appcelerator-mobile, commonjs

How can i pass events through module hierarchy?

I have the main *app.js*, there i load the module *welcome.js* (with `require("welcome")` ) as a window and inside welcome i load modules *home.js* (the view containing the login and register buttons) and *login.js*. The problem is i don't know what is the right method to notify *app.js* and *welcome.js* about events in *login.js*. For example when the user wants to go back, inside the *welcome* i have to hide *login* and show *home*, when the user logs in i have to destroy the *welcome* and load *main.js* inside *app.js*.

Should i create a callback in *app.js* and pass it to *welcome* which passes it to *login*, create a global event listener in app and fire an event in *login*, or is there a better way i haven't found yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is to use application level event

in login.js fire an application level event :

```
Ti.App.fireEvent('yourEventName',{
                                   msg:'this is an event from login'
                                  });
```

and in other file (welcome.js or app.js) listen to your event :

```
Ti.App.addEventListener('yourEventName',function(e){
                                  alert(e.msg);
  });
```